# Ubuntu Install Freezing

Tags: system-installation

When I put my disk with Ubuntu in, it freezes the second time it asks to select a language (the page after I select to install Ubuntu.)

> I ran the disk check and nothing was faulty.
>   I have 6GB RAM, 4.64 available
>   I have 600GB Hard Drive with 596 available.
>   Computer processor is AMD Anthlon(tm) II x4 620 Processor, 2600 Mhz, 4 cores

[image]

So, it seems my computer should definitely be able to run Ubuntu. And the disk is not flawed. What issue am I having?

Comment: I don't have a usb?

Comment: did you try to install on a new ext4 partition?

Comment: No I don't even know what that means. I just followed the instructions the Ubuntu website gives.

Comment: did you had windows installed on the same pc?

Comment: Yeah there's Windows on the PC

Comment: http://imgur.com/i7XLFK3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to resize the `c` drive(596 GB) to create a new ext4 partition,so that the Ubuntu would be installed.For this just follow the below steps,

  1. Boot your `Ubuntu installation disk`. Click on `Try Ubuntu`. After that, open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run the below commands to install gparted partition editor

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted
     ```
  2. Right-click on the 596 GB partition and click on *Resize/Move* option to create an unallocated space of how much size did you want for Ubuntu.After that click on *apply*, an unallocated space was created just below to the 596 GB partition.
  3. create a new ext4 filesystem from that unallocated space.
  4. Now run the ubuntu installer,and choose *something else* option to install Ubuntu on the created ext4 filesystem.

Comment: I don't get a "try Ubuntu" option when I boot the disk.

Comment: ubuntu desktop live disk not ubuntu server live disk.

Comment: I'm sorry dude, I have no idea what the difference is. I booted the disk and I didn't get that option.

Comment: you created a ubuntu server live disk,did you had ubuntu desktop iso file?

Comment: Oh Gods apparently not.. Guess I just downloaded the wrong thing then.

Comment: don't worry download the ubuntu desktop version and then create a ubuntu-desktop live disk,then follow my answer to install ubuntu-desktop.